# Ruby - variable isn't NULL and contains a string

Tags: ruby, null, if-statement, conditional-statements

I am storing in DB table data. In a column could be the value **NULL** and a string. And I can't to find a condition, when is a string -> print this string, when is **NULL**, do something else...

I am trying something like this:

```
if @optional.logo.size > 3  && !@optional.logo.nil?
  ...In table is a STRING...
else
  ...In table is NULL...
end
```

but this is wrong... Can anyone help me, please, how to fix it?
Thanks you

Comment: this could fail if @optional is nil as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to test for nil first because a nil object will not have the `size` property.

Answer (score 3):

Switch it around and do the `nil` check first:

```
if !@optional.logo.nil? && @optional.logo.size > 3
```

The `&&` operator is what is called "short circuiting". That means that if the first argument evaluates to false the second is never evaluated, since it wouldn't matter. In other words, if the first argument is false the whole expression will be false regardless of the argument part. The `||` operator works similarly, but does not evaluate the second argument if the first is true, since that makes the whole expression true regardless of the second argument's value.

By checking for `nil` first you avoid the issue that `nil` will not have a `size` method, since that part of the expression will never be evaluated.